# Translate categories in custom built multi language site

Tags: categories, multi-language

Anyone knows how translate category names using this method?

http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine

Comment: Do you want to translate Category URL title too? Or just the category name?

Comment: Only category name...

Comment: Have you looked at custom category fields with a similar naming construct?

Comment: OMG!!! It's very simple. Thank you and sorry but I'm a rookie!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy.

Create a new [Category Field](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_field_management.html) and prefix its name with the language prefix related and use it for the translated name. For example, `pt-category_name`.

On your templates, inside [categories variable pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#categories), for example:

```
{if language == "pt"}{pt-category_name}{/if}
{if language == "en"}{category_name}{/if}{!-- being `en` your default language --}
```